# Only show alphabet on keyboard (disable numbers and punctuation)

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the comment section of my app I bring up the keyboard to add a comment. When a comment is added all is send via a $_GET to the database. That makes I can't have numbers or strange characters in my comment (querystring), or the call will be disabled. Instead of filtering all data is there a simple way to prevent the user from entering numbers an punctuation on the keyboard? I thought following line might work, but it didn't:

```
self.txtComment.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
```

Any other suggestions or code snippets of a custom keyboard layout with this functionality?

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue ?

Comment: @bllakjakk your snippet is tested and approved, works perfect and filters characters you specify in the NSCharacterSet. Thanks for your answer +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible but a workaround can be as below:

Below UITextFieldDelegate implementaion method will remove any other character that you do not desire from the textField as soon as it is typed.

HaveFun.

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)textEntered {
    for (int i = 0; i < [textEntered length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [textEntered characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([charSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Also you need to define your character set:

i.e.

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abc ... whatever you want"];
```

Comment: Specifically, select for characters that belong to the lowercase and uppercase character sets.